# Shutdown does not power off computer with db derby service

Tags: 12.04, java, shutdown, database

I set service db derby by this instructions [Fresh Install Ubuntu 12.10 - 17. apache db derby](https://sites.google.com/a/webarts.ca/toms-blog/Blog/new-blog-items/freshinstallubuntu1210recoveringfromhdfailure)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Startup script for Derby
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          derby
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     91 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      20 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Apache Derby DB at boot time.
# Description:       Provides a small simple java based DB.
### END INIT INFO#
# chk con fig: 345 94 16
# description: Derby startup script
# to enable on bootup on redhat "chkconfig --level 35 derby on"
# to enable on bootup on debian "update-rc.d derby defaults" or the
# slightly longer (but better run levels) "update-rc.d derby start 91 2 3 4 5  . stop 20 0 1 6 ."

# see http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2009/09/30/one-java-init-script/

HOMEDIR=/opt/db-derby
DERBY_USER=derby
APPNAME=Derby

# see http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheDerby/article.html  for startUp Options
RUNCOMMAND="bin/startNetworkServer  -h 0.0.0.0"
STOCOMMAND=bin/stopNetworkServer
LOGFILE=/var/log/derby.log
...
```

When derby is running

```
service derby status
Derby ( PIDs 1503  ) is running.
```

I cannot shutdown computer with power off. Shutdown ended in login screen.

When I stop derby

```
sudo service derby stop
```

then I can shutdown computer with power off normally.

What I should do to shutdown - power off computer correctly with running service db derby?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I write my own service script. Now db derby works as expected.

Setting Apache DB Derby under Ubuntu 12.04 as service.

Copy file `derby` to directory `/etc/init.d/`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Startup script for Derby
#
# description: Derby startup script
# to enable on bootup on debian "update-rc.d derby defaults" or the
# to disable on bootup on debian "update-rc.d derby remove"


DBDIR=/var/db/derby
APPCOMMAND=/opt/db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin/bin/NetworkServerControl

start() {
    echo -n "Derby Starting: "
    cd $DBDIR
    sudo -u derby mv derby.2.log derby.3.log
    sudo -u derby mv derby.1.log derby.2.log 
    sudo -u derby mv derby.log derby.1.log 
    sudo -u derby $APPCOMMAND start -h 0.0.0.0 &
    sudo -u derby sleep 3
    sudo -u derby chmod 644 derby.log 
}

stop() {
echo -n $"Derby Shutting down: "
    $APPCOMMAND shutdown &
}

status() {
    echo "Derby has status: "
    $APPCOMMAND ping
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
     stop)
        stop
        ;;
     restart)
        stop
        sleep 3
        start
        ;;
     status)
        status
        ;;
     *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
     exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Then install script as service by command `update-rc.d derby defaults`.

Uninstall script by command `update-rc.d derby remove`.

Set directory `/var/db/derby` to owner `derby`.

```
sidlo64@ubuntu:/var/db$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 srp 24 16:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root  root  4096 srp 26 06:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 derby derby 4096 srp 24 22:28 derby
```

For manually stop database use `service derby stop`.

For manually start database use `sudo service derby start`.

Comment: I must create file DERBY (used listing # Startup script for Derby) and copy to /etc/init.d/. Right? Why after try to start - update-rc.d derby defaults, OS return - root@hadoop02:/home/hadoopuser# update-rc.d derby defaults
insserv: script derby is not an executable regular file, skipped!?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a bug which might be fixed by re-installing gnome-keyring, Or the Derby service, Try the normal Shutdown from terminal :

```
sudo halt
```

OR even the force Shutdown

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

In addition, you can make a small script which first stops derby service and then do the shutdown.

Comment: It is not good advice. I know how to shutdown computer from command line. I need solution for common user who is able only click to menu Shutdown.